# Dependency Injection using web.config in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'd like to utilize Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC 5. The mappings between types and interfaces need to be stored in web.config. Is there anything built-in the ASP.NET MVC 5 for dependency injection from web.config? Or, do I use Unity?

Answer (score 2):

> I often think that people are over-eager to define configuration
>   files. Often a programming language makes a straightforward and
>   powerful configuration mechanism. 
>   *- Martin Fowler*

If you are new to Dependency Injection, do not use XML *(or web.config)* for configuration. ***XML configuration*** is a very old technology, and tends to be verbose and brittle.

Instead, you want to use ***CODE AS CONFIGURATION*** unless you need *late binding*. Mainly, you want to use generics and Fluent Builders used by configuration APIs.

*Yes, you can use Unity container, if you really want to use XML-centric of DI Container.*

*You can read more about XML vs Code configuration at [Dependency Injection in .NET (Paperback) by Mark Seemann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) - Page 67*.